# Vscode api - select file like dropdown

Tags: typescript, api, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on a vscode extension.

Currently, I am retrieving all the .h from the workspace folder. And I would like the user to be able to select the .h he wants and he can select it like in the picture below, but with the .h retrieved before.:

[image: Example photo]

Do you have an idea of how to do it? Or the name of this feature so that I can refer to the documentation because I can not find its name.

Comment: search for `QuickPick`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer I'm posting it here, if anyone has the same question as me.

```
let items: vscode.QuickPickItem[] = [
      {
        label: "Test1 Label",
        description: "Test1 Description",
        detail: "$(files) Test1 Detail with icon",
      },
      {
        label: "Test2 Label",
        description: "Test2 Description",
        detail: "$(files) Test2 Detail with icon",
      },
    ];
```

For the display.

```
vscode.window.showQuickPick(items);
```

[Exemple](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PKgRI.png)

And thanks to rioV8 for the help